# NIDAQmx yosemite compatibility

Tags: osx-yosemite, nidaqmx

I've installed osx 10.10 ( Yosemite ) and since then the device (NI-USB 6210) is not working anymore.
The problem is obviously driver related. I called National Instruments and they confirmed the issue, and they also told me that the problem will be probably fixed in the next release of the nidaqmx, that will happen not so soon.
So their suggestion is to downgrade to Mavericks, which kinda suck.
They also told me to check the compatibility table

http://www.ni.com/labview/os-support/i/

in order to know when if will be supported, until then I have to struggle with downgrade or find a workaround which would be the best thing. anybody found a solution to this problem lately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your device and how you program it, you should be able to get it working on Yosemite using NI-DAQmx Base 14.0 [1].

NI-DAQmx Base 14.0 does not claim Yosemite support, but after inspecting the installer and running a few tests, here is what I have determined:

- The installer, kernel extensions, frameworks, and applications are signed by National Instruments, which means Gatekeeper won't interrupt you with "are you sure you want to do this?" questions.
- Both 32-bit and 64-bit LabVIEW APIs are provided.
- Both 32-bit and 64-bit C APIs are provided, but a C or Cocoa application emits a warning on exit. It appears one of the components in the driver attempts to access UI elements from a background thread. My suspicion is that the LabVIEW Run-Time Engine, in which the DAQmx Base C API runs, is doing that.

> ### Links
>
> [1] **NI-DAQmx Base 14.0 for Mac**
>   
> http://www.ni.com/download/ni-daqmx-base-14.0/5060/en/

Comment: cool I'll give it a shot! and, plus one for your avatar. IT Crowd rulez ;)

Comment: btw, the device I'm using is a USB-6210 and I need to run a C application.. so we'll see

Comment: Thanks :-) I would expect the USB-6210 to work from the C API, but you'll see warnings emitted on exit in the Terminal. The framework is 'fat', so both the 32-bit and 64-bit architectures are in the binary.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, and spent an evening figuring out the problem.

Apparently, the NiDaq framework tries to send a message setHandler:withData: to the appdelegate. On yosemite, this handler no longer exists, causing the exception.

If you haven't implemented such message in your own app delegate, things go bad.

But you can simply implement a dummy handler by adding this to your application delegate class :

```
- (id)setHandler:(id)a withData:(id) b
{
        return nil;
}
```

this way, the framework doesn't crash !!! I still have to test if the measured data is correct, but at least i'm running again !

Comment: since the NIDaq topic is so low-volume, this answer probably won't see many upvotes. i just wanted to personally say THANK YOU for this. hopefully you can feel the good cheer via comments instead of votes for now. i had the setHandler:withData crash in my app, and this SAVED ME! Thanks so much.

Comment: i can't locate any reference (even an obsolete one) for what "setHandler:withData:" was ever supposed to be used for in any Cocoa app. do you happen to know?

Comment: no ; i have no idea what it does... I just saw it scroll by in the debugger and figured I'd give it a shot !

**side note** : our uni has a support contract with national instruments so I contacted them. They hope to release a yosemite version around november. Unfortunately, el capitan is now already released so I expect more problems